# How to read files with separators in Python and append characters at the end?

Tags: python, append, startswith

I have a file format that looks like this

```
 >1ATGC>2TTTT>3ATGC>$$$>B1ATCG>B2TT-G>3TTCG>B4TT-G>B5TTCG>B6TTCG$$$>C1TTTT>C2ATGC
```

Note: "$$$" divides the file, such that anything before $$$ is Set 1 and after $$$ is Set 2 and after the next $$$ Set3 etc.

I have to do the following:

a. Concatenate the sequences following ">". So, I have to join "ATGC" "TTTT" "ATGC" and store in (1) and I have to concatenate "ATCG" "TT-G" "TTCG" "TT-G" "TTCG""TTCG" and store as (2)... concatenate again and store in (3)

The output should be a list that looks like:

```
("ATGCTTTTATGC","ATCGTT-GTTCGTT-GTTCGTTCG","TTTTATGC")
```

(2) Then, I find the the Set that has the maximum length => here Set(2)

(3) If length of Set i is not equal to Set (2), then I add "Z" at the end Set i, such that length of Set i is now equal to length of Set (2)

(4) I replace all "-" with "Z"

The output should look like:

```
 ("ATGCTTTTATGCZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
 "ATCGTTZGTTCGTTZGTTCGTTCG",
 "TTTTATGCZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ")
```

Here is the code, I have attempted:

```
in_file = open('c:/test.txt','r')
org = []
seqlist = []
seqstring = ""

for line in in_file:
    if line.startswith("$$$"):
         if seqstring!= "":
            seqlist.append(seqstring)
            seqstring = ""
         org.append(line.rstrip("\n"))
    elif line.startswith(">"):
        seqstring += line.rstrip("\n")
seqlist.append(seqstring)

setdraft = seqlist
maxsetlength = max(len(seqlist))

setdraft2 =[]  

for i in setdraft:
     if len(i) != maxsetlength:
         setdraft2 = i.append("Z")

setfinal =[]

for j in setdraft2:
     if j in setdraft2 =="-":
         setfinal = j.insert ("Z")
```

The above script does not work. It gives me multiple errors. 
Eg. When I print `setdraft` it gives me the output

```
['>1ATGC>2TTTT>3ATGC>$$$>B1ATCG>B2TT-G>3TTCG>B4TT-G>B5TTCG>B‌​6TTCG$$$>C1TTTT>C2AT‌​GC']
```

which is the same as the input

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/trial.py", line 25, in <module>
    maxsetlength = max(len(seqlist))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: So does the code work? If not, what output does it produce instead (including the  full traceback for any errors)?

Comment: No, till now I'm afraid not. When I print "setdraft" it gives me the output ['>1ATGC>2TTTT>3ATGC>$$$>B1ATCG>B2TT-G>3TTCG>B4TT-G>B5TTCG>B6TTCG$$$>C1TTTT>C2ATGC'] ===> which is the same as the input

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/trial.py", line 25, in <module>
    maxsetlength = max(len(seqlist))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: I have done the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how fragile your data set is, but if it follows the pattern above (namely the last 4 characters are the ones you are looking for) then you can use a couple of `split()`s and `itertools.zip_longest` and `zip` it back to append the `Z`

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> import string
>>> def digit_index(s):
...     for i, c in enumerate(s):
...         if c in string.digits:
...             return i
...     return 0
...
>>> s = '>1ATGC>2TTTT>3ATGC>$$$>B1ATCG>B2TT-G>3TTCG>B4TT-G>B5TTCG>B6TTCG$$$>C1TTTT>C2ATGC'
>>> parsed = [''.join(y[digit_index(y)+1:].replace('-', 'Z') for y in x.split('>')) for x in s.split('$$$')]
>>> parsed
['ATGCTTTTATGC', 'ATCGTTZGTTCGTTZGTTCGTTCG', 'TTTTATGC']
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(*it.zip_longest(*parsed, fillvalue='Z'))]
['ATGCTTTTATGCZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
 'ATCGTTZGTTCGTTZGTTCGTTCG',
 'TTTTATGCZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ']
```

If you don't mind it as a list then you can avoid `join()`ing it back to a string:

```
>>> list(zip(*it.zip_longest(*parsed, fillvalue='Z')))
[('A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'), 
 ('A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'Z', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'Z', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G'),
 ('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z')]
```

Comment: Do I have to import something to use zip? I get this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zip_longest'

Comment: `import itertools as it` for `it.zip_longest` - `zip` is a standard builtin and doesn't need an import.

Comment: I just need to clarify this - I don't understand why you inserted (y[-4:]) as part of the code? And why is it that you ask if I'm interested in "namely the last 4 characters are the ones you are looking for"?  Also, I keep running into this AttirbuteError, even after I use the itertools

Comment: Also, you are right. My data is is new lines. So I need to use  .strip function (as I have used in the original script)

Comment: `'1ATGC'[-4:] == 'ATGC'` and `'B4TT-G'[-4:] == 'TT-G'` which seems to be the bit you are trying to retain when you `split()` on `>`. Ahh, you are probably using python2 - in python2 `zip_longest` is called `izip_longest`. If you need to `strip()` off newlines then you can simply add it to `s.strip().split('$$$')`

Comment: The strip and izip solves the problem. Thankyou. However, I am not interested in only the last 4 characters of the code. It should be able to take in any length of sequence with the letters A, T, G, C and "-". For instance: s = '>1GAGGGGGGAAT$$$>B1-TTTA$$$>C1CC-CA'

Comment: Then you will have to put more logic in the slice to take 1 (`1`) or 2 (`B1`) characters off the front of the `split()`. Is it always the first `$$$` that has only one character vs the remaining takes of 2 characters.

Comment: No, it can be '>A1GAGGGGGGAAT$$$>B1-TTTA$$$>C1CC-CA' or '>1GAGGGGGGAAT$$$>B1-TTTA$$$>C1CC-CA' . These files that one obtains for research purposes can have varied starters.

Comment: Then I'm assuming you need everything after the first digit. So you need to get the index of the first digit and `y[digit_index(y)+1:]` - see update.

Comment: Hi! I was running my code with the inputs as above, but for some reason the .strip function does not seem to work. My output continues to have /n marked everywhere. My entire code is here https://eval.in/658293. Do I have to place .strip function elsewhere?